# React Component Button + Icon Component disappears on added Padding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to create a button (React Component), animated where a circle appears with another react component inside as the SVG. As soon as I add the padding to the SVG Component it gets hidden for some reason. I have tried searching but got no results on this case.

The code I am using to create this is:

```
<Button variant="cornered" color="quaternary" href="#">
    <ArrowUp className="hidden scale-75 rounded-full bg-white fill-tertiary-400" />
    Request a demo
</Button>
```

Initial state is the following:

[image: Initial button]

When background color added through tailwinds bg-white
[image: With background color]

Adding a p-3 tailwind value hides the SVG?
[image: padding added]

Now I could solve the problem by adding a rounded div as background in this case but it's not the way I want to solve the problem. Is it possible to add the padding without making the SVG component disappear?

Comment: Alright that was the reason why the SVG was hidden, I fixed the problem by making the ArrowUp component absolute so it doesn't go out of sight. placed it left and added extra padding-left on the button on hover. I thought this was a bug in react but apparently way easier to fix. Still new to react and sometimes things won't work the way I am used to due vanilla CSS / HTML. Thanks mate for helping me fix this problem for me!

Comment: Please take the [tour]. As I said, you need to provide and accept an answer. A resolved post with no answer does the community no good.

Comment: Because it was placed as comments there is no possibility to mark it as solved.

Comment: I did that because there wasn't enough information in the question to be sure. There still isn't.

Comment: Actually there was and your answer was good Enough to tell me and the viewers that the padding pushes the SVG out of the element. Thanks anyway, marked the thread as solved.

Comment: I was guessing with no way to verify. There wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The p-3 class adds .75rem of padding](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding) all the way around the element. That doesn't leave room for the SVG, which is either shrunk or shifted.